# Connecting To a URL through java in Blackberry

Tags: java, network-programming, blackberry-simulator

I am trying to connect to a URL through a Java program in Blackberry simulator. But it is not connecting.

```
   try { 
        HttpConnection httpConn;
        StreamConnection s;
        s = (StreamConnection)Connector.open("http://www.google.com/");
        httpConn = (HttpConnection)s;
        status = httpConn.getResponseCode();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int t=0;
    if (status == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
    {
        add(new RichTextField("Successfully Authorized", Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
    }
```

Comment: Have you started the [MDS Simulator](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/5716/The_BB_MDS_Simulator_447180_11.jsp) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
s = (StreamConnection)Connector.open("http://www.google.com"+";deviceside=true");
```

try with this line...
If you are trying in emulator means use deviceside=true
If its in a mobile means for wifi connection you have to use interface=wifi